# Hölder continuity for parabolic equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces

What is a good and modern reference for hölder regularity for non-degenerate parabolic equations?
To be a bit more precise, I have a degenerate parabolic equation, exhibiting two degeneracies, and can do the whole stuff with energy and logarithmic estimates to reduce the oscillation if it is large. For these estimates, I exploit a certain growth of some functions near its sup and inf (there the degeneracies occur). However, during that process one reaches the case where no or at most one degeneracies occur and I'm not able to use the growth of these functions.

Hence, I need to adapt the process and the cylinders occuring in the procedure (and potentially I might even forget in the case of no degeneracies the logarithmic estimates?).
Any recommendations?

Comment: ([tag:reference-request]) should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

Comment: Did you try *Degenerate Parabolic Equations* by DiBenedetto?

Comment: The problem is that DiBenedetto's book only use degeneracies in the gradient. My equation is more of porous medium type. i.e. the principal part is of the form $\Nabla \cdot \Phi'(s)\nabla s$ (in the correct interpretation). However, to me even that proof is to complicated to show the essential ideas on local Hölder regularity.

Comment: Did you try Vazquez's book on the porous medium equation? In it he considers the Holder continuity of solutions. I don't know much about this area so apologies if I am missing something.

Comment: Vazquez, is also missing a huge part of the details (if not to say almost all of the details :) ) I think, the most detailed, and again hard to read literature on this is an article of Porzio and Vespri. Thanks for your efforts riem.